# Ubuntu Installation not working in intel RST mode

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I want to install ubuntu in ssd in dual boot but the bios mode is in INTEL RST so the ubuntu setup don't detect ssd,but when I switch it to AHCI mode my windows setup doesn't start it only works in Intel RST

Comment: You've not provided any release details which maybe helpful. Are you asking about Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? or a Ubuntu Core product, and which release?

Comment: I suggest you google how to install AHCI support in Windows which is what you need to do before changing the mode to AHCI.

Comment: But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Sorry for late comment but his just helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intel RST**

You've got a single SSD/HDD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD/HDD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

**Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!**

**Source:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
- Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

  - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.